# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException after Server side validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, weblogic, facelets

I have a registration form with multiple fields. For most of the fields , I am performing the required and regular expression validations. Everything works fine but on the form I am also performing a server side validation to check if the user is present in the end system.
If the user is already present then I am displaying an error message on the same form. Now when i update the user and press submit I am getting the below error. Works fine otherwise

```
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:161)
```

I am using Primefaces 3.0 on Weblogic 10.3.5
The jsf jars being used jsf-api-2.0.3-b05.jar and jsf-impl-2.0.3-b05.jar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As first thing, I'd upgrade the 3 year old Mojarra 2.0.3 to something more recent, just to exclude that it isn't just one of the many old bugs in Mojarra's state management system.

Comment: There's not really enough information here to help you without seeing the code...